# Trying to understand the different structures of JSON data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

HI I am working on different JSON structures, I am having two JSON data which I am currently working which is having array of objects. I am trying to understand the structure of the JSON, because when I am working on the JSON data I am struggling to get the values out of it. I am seeking help where any body can explain me the data structure and how to get the values out of it. Any one can explain me how to work with below JSON data.

```
//MOCK DATA ONE

[
    {
      "key": "row-0",
  
      "cells": [
        {
          "key": "cell-0",
          "id": "ID-0",
          "headerName": "Name",
          "CustomerName": "CR One",
          "CustomerID": "P-01",
          "CustomerNumber": "123456789"
        }
      ]
    },
  
    {
      "key": "row-1",
      "cells": [
        {
          "key": "cell-1",
          "id": "ID-1",
          "headerName": "Name",
           "CustomerName": "CR Two",
          "CustomerID": "P-02",
          "CustomerNumber": "123456789"
        }
      ]
    },

    {
        "key": "row-2",
        "cells": [
          {
            "key": "cell-2",
            "id": "ID-2",
            "headerName": "Name",
            "CustomerName": "CR Three",
           "CustomerID": "P-03",
           "CustomerNumber": "123456789"
          }
        ]
      },

      {
        "key": "row-3",
        "cells": [
          {
            "key": "cell-3",
            "id": "ID-3",
            "headerName": "Name",
            "CustomerName": "CR Four",
           "CustomerID": "P-04",
           "CustomerNumber": "123456789"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "row-4",
        "cells": [
          {
            "key": "cell-4",
            "id": "ID-4",
            "headerName": "Name",
            "CustomerName": "CR Five",
           "CustomerID": "P-05",
           "CustomerNumber": "123456789"
          }
        ]
    }
  ]



//Mock Data Two

[

  {
  
    "key":"row-0",

  "cells":[
  
  {"key":"cell-0","id":"ID-0","headerName":"customerName","customerName":"Customer One"},
  
  {"key":"cell-1","id":"ID-1","headerName":"CustomerRegID","CustomerRegID":"C-01"},

  {"key":"cell-2","id":"ID-2","headerName":"CustomerNumber","CustomerNumber":"1234567890"},
  
  {"key":"cell-3","id":"ID-3","headerName":"CustomerLabel","CustomerLabel":["Reg","Temp"]}
  ]
},
  
  {"key":"row-1",

  "cells":[

    {"key":"cell-0","id":"ID-0","headerName":"customerName","customerName":"Customer Two"},
  
   {"key":"cell-1","id":"ID-1","headerName":"CustomerRegID","CustomerRegID":"C-02"},

   {"key":"cell-2","id":"ID-2","headerName":"CustomerNumber","CustomerNumber":"1234567890"},
  
   {"key":"cell-3","id":"ID-3","headerName":"CustomerLabel","CustomerLabel":["Reg","Temp"]}
  ]
},
{"key":"row-2",

  "cells":[

 
    {"key":"cell-0","id":"ID-0","headerName":"customerName","customerName":"Customer Three"},
  
   {"key":"cell-1","id":"ID-1","headerName":"CustomerRegID","CustomerRegID":"C-03"},

   {"key":"cell-2","id":"ID-2","headerName":"CustomerNumber","CustomerNumber":"1234567890"},
  
   {"key":"cell-3","id":"ID-3","headerName":"CustomerLabel","CustomerLabel":["Reg","Temp"]}
  ]
},
{"key":"row-3",

  "cells":[
    {"key":"cell-0","id":"ID-0","headerName":"customerName","customerName":"Customer Four"},
  
   {"key":"cell-1","id":"ID-1","headerName":"CustomerRegID","CustomerRegID":"C-04"},

   {"key":"cell-2","id":"ID-2","headerName":"CustomerNumber","CustomerNumber":"1234567890"},
  
   {"key":"cell-3","id":"ID-3","headerName":"CustomerLabel","CustomerLabel":["Reg","Temp"]}
  ]
},
{"key":"row-4",

  "cells":[

    {"key":"cell-0","id":"ID-0","headerName":"customerName","customerName":"Customer Five"},
  
   {"key":"cell-1","id":"ID-1","headerName":"CustomerRegID","CustomerRegID":"C-05"},

   {"key":"cell-2","id":"ID-2","headerName":"CustomerNumber","CustomerNumber":"1234567890"},
  
   {"key":"cell-3","id":"ID-3","headerName":"CustomerLabel","CustomerLabel":["Reg","Temp"]}
  ]
}
]
```

//Logic this logic worked for Mock Data one but not for mock Data

```
{mockData.map((values, index) => {
        console.log("VALUES", values);
        return values.cells.map(({ headerName, ...rest }) => {
          console.log("JSON", JSON.stringify(rest));
          console.log("REST", rest.CustomerName);---> getting undefined(I tried many approach everything is giving me undefined)
        });
      })}
```

Comment: This question is too vague. What do you want to accomplish? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @testing_22, I am trying to understand the difference , when I am doing some operation with map both are resulting different output. Hence I am trying to understand the difference first before applying any method to perform some operation

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is a `list` of `objects` with the attributes `key` and `cells`.

`key` is of type string and `cells` is another list of `objects`. Your cell objects have some mandatory fields like `key`, `id` and `headerName` and some optional fields e.g. `CustomerRegID` or `CustomerLabel`.

If you struggle with getting values from JSON I would highly recommend using TypeScript. Your first set of data equals to these types:

```
type RootObject = RootItem[]

type RootItem = {
  key: string;
  cells: CellItem[];
}

type CellItem = {
  key: string;
  id: string;
  headerName: string;
  CustomerName: string;
  CustomerID: string;
  CustomerNumber: string;
};
```

Once typed, accessing them is very simple.

```
const myJson: RootObject = [...]

console.log(myJson[0].key);                   // "row-0"
console.log(myJson[0].cells[0].key);          // "cell-0"
console.log(myJson[0].cells[1].CustomerName); // "CR Two"
```